# iOS 7 fullscreen web app delay in firing javascript touchend

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a standalone web application that used to work fine with iOS 6.

With iOS 7 I noticed that there is a significant delay (several seconds) in firing the javascript touchend event after a finger swipe. The behavior is not consistent, sometimes the first swipe generates the event immediately and only the following ones are delayed.

Is this a known issue and/or there is a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 7.0.3 :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing this same problem with an HTML5 game I'm developing.  Sometimes the touchend would seem to fire immediately, and other times there would be a delay of several seconds before it fired.

I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782212/2769186) reminding me of the setTimeout 0 trick for pushing a block of javascript onto the queue for later processing. I was doing a bit of "heavy-lifting" (some DOM manipulation) inside the touchend event handler, and this appeared to disrupt its firing.

I wrapped the code inside my touchend handler with a setTimeout, and that eliminated the delay:

```
$(document).on('touchend', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do stuff here...
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This patched the iOS 7.0 bug. Hopefully iOS 7.1 will fix the bug for good and won't require such workaround anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS 7 and HTML5: problems, changes and new APIs: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Comment: I saw that article already, but there's no reference to standalone web apps having issues with touch events (it just mentions a lot of issues with web apps, I was looking for something more specific than that).

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7.1 seems to fix this issue; touchend events fire properly (even without the zero timeout)